# How do I replace a file in an ISO file without needing root from the command line

Tags: command-line, iso

I have an ISO file and I want to change the contents of one of the files in it from the command line. I know that I can use

```
sudo mount -o loop <etc...>
rsync -ra a b
edit b/file
mkisofs <options>
```

but I need a solution that does not require root permissions.

Comment: This will tell how and more: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/96625/allow-non-superusers-to-mount-any-filesystem Technically not a question about Ubuntu but about Linux so our sister site will have more hits on this ;)

Comment: Thank you, but I was hoping to find a way to do the unpacking in a way that avoids the mounting all together. ISO is just a file containing other files, after all.

Comment: Thank you for the pointer to unix.stackexchange.com, but I guess it is too late to move it now. http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/64068/is-cross-posting-a-question-on-multiple-stack-exchange-sites-permitted-if-the-qu

Comment: An ISO is a filesystem. It is more similar to a harddisk than to a file (hence the need to mount it ;) ) Moving is not needed; it'll get answered and/or closed in time ;)

Comment: You can extract the contents of an ISO directly using 7zip.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

I finally managed to find an answer myself. I can use fuse to mount the ISO file, there is even a tool for this in the Ubuntu repositories:

```
sudo apt-get install fuseiso
```

Then I can do:

```
fuseiso -p file.iso mounted_iso/
rsync -ra mounted_iso/ copy/
fusermount -u mounted_iso

chmod -R +w copy/
edit copy/file

mkisofs <many options> -o remastered.iso copy/
```

Comment: Don't forget to upvote and accept. Here's a +1 from me :)

Comment: Seems fair that others get two days to try to come up with an even better solution. For example it might be that somebody could come up with a solution that would not even require fuse.